# Change Cover Photo Without Uploading again

Tags: facebook, photos

I have a photo uploaded in an album that I want to set as the cover photo for my Profile. Is there a way to do so without downloading the photo and upload it again?

When I open the photo, under the "Options" I see, "Set as Profile Photo" but there is no "Set as Cover Photo".

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is. Visit your profile page, click on the `Change Cover` link at the bottom left of your cover image, then `Choose from Photos...`.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Of course it's possbile, I read a guide yesterday, simple and easy to use, the guide are at this address. With this script you can upload [facebook covers](http://covermaker.net/) via js with just one click.

This is the url: [How to upload Facebook Cover Photo to Facebook via Javascript](http://socialdevelopers.wordpress.com/2013/01/03/upload-facebook-covers-javascript/)

Comment: Please disclose your affiliation with the service you mentioned, otherwise your answer will be considered spam and treated accordingly. Thanks!